# JPA: PGobject cannot be cast

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, casting

I'm using JPA for the first time and I'm getting this error when I try to query the postgres database:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.util.PGobject cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

The code is:

```
List<Results> r = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT r FROM RESULTS r\n"
            + "INNER JOIN SESSION S ON s.SESSION_ID = r.SESSION_ID WHERE s.SESSION_ID = '" + sessionId + "'").getResultList();
```

I've already tried with Object[], but the error still the same

```
List<Object[]> r = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT r FROM RESULTS r\n"
            + "INNER JOIN SESSION S ON s.SESSION_ID = r.SESSION_ID WHERE s.SESSION_ID = '" + sessionId + "'").getResultList();
```

Someone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you are using JPQL syntax for a nativeQuery, have you tried this code with the createQuery method()?

```
List<Results> r = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM RESULTS r\n"
            + "INNER JOIN SESSION S ON s.SESSION_ID = r.SESSION_ID WHERE s.SESSION_ID = '" + sessionId + "'").getResultList();
```

If the sql is correct and you are using a native query, does

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(SELECT * FROM RESULTS r\n"
                + "INNER JOIN SESSION S ON s.SESSION_ID = r.SESSION_ID WHERE s.SESSION_ID = '" + sessionId + "'");
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
```

Return without a class cast exception?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I was using createQuery but this method gives me sintax errors. So I started using createNativeQuery with SQL code. The code above is SQL and its right, since it works in postgres console.

Comment: What happens if you attempt to return a List<PGObject>?

Comment: Doing a quick lookup of PGObject it states PGobject is a class used to describe unknown types An unknown type is any type that is unknown by JDBC Standards.  If it doesn't work, I'd simplify the sql statement...to see if it can be mapped with one or two columns.

Comment: Updated answer with nativeQuery example using select * instead of r.  Hopefully this wont return a PGObject.  If it does I'd turn on show sql and see what your jpa provider is sending to your db.

Comment: No problem, my guess is that the "SELECT r FROM RESULTS r" portion of your query wasn't mapping correctly and giving you the PGObject.  Usually when I see something like "SELECT r FROM RESULTS r" I assume its jpql, which would give you List<Results>.  If that query works in the Postgres console, it could be valid postgres sql, but not valid sql for your jpa implementation. For example if I wanted to run the same sql on Oracle, "SELECT r FROM RESULTS r" would yield the  "R": invalid identifier error.  Instead i would have to say "SELECT r.* FROM RESULTS r"

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that you're using SQL and not JPQL then why aren't you just using this?

```
List<Object> result = query.getResultList();
```

Since you're only selecting a single column in the SQL then makes more sense for each row to map to an Object.